# Issue with .on('error')

Tags: jquery

I want to take 'data-defaulting' from '.check-img' if its 'src' returns an error, and then assign the value to its sibling source's src.

The idea is to check for the mobile version image available or not and if not, take the default value and display the default image in mobile by assigning that as srcset to mobile source.

This seems to be not working, and the request for the image which is not present is repeatedly happening.

```
<picture>

    <!-- Mobile image -->
    <source srcset="data-defaultimg value should be here if .check-img (mobile image src) returns error" media="(max-width:768px)">

    <!-- Virtual image with desktop image as data-defaultImage value --> 
    <img style="display: none" src="mobile image src here" alt="" class="check-img" data-defaultimg="default src here">

    <!-- Desktop image. -->
    <img src="desktop-img-src" alt="" class="img-fluid">

</picture>
```

jQuery for checking the error and assigning "defaultimg" value to mobile image srcset.

```
$("picture img.check-img").each(function(){
  $(this).on('error', function(){
    $(this).siblings("source").attr("srcset", $(this).data('defaultimg'));
  })
});
```

I am not sure why the missing image request keeps on going. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: A display:none image may not even download

Comment: Yes, just remove `display: none;`, the image is not even loaded, that's why it will never fail.

Comment: Tried removing 'display: none', but still, it does the same.

Comment: Ok, let me check

Comment: I reproduce it and it works. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @muecas, assume the image in '.check-img' is not present in the server, then that image request keeps on going.
Btw, at that time 'defaultimg' is setting correctly to 'source' without any problem.

Comment: I created a fully functional example. The source for the hidden image does not exist, so it triggers the error and set the`scrset` that gets from `data-defaultimg`. That works perfectly. Please create a fiddle or something showing the error.

Comment: @muecas, https://codepen.io/ganeshkg007/pen/gzyaRw
check the console, if you are not getting first time - try clearing cache and hard reload and then watch console.

Comment: What should i get? The image not loading? It loads perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171574/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-g-and-muecas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid loading the not found image repeatedly, just remove the error event after the error is processed.

```js
$("picture img.check-img").each(function() {
  $(this).on('error', function() {
    $(this).off('error');
    $(this).siblings("source").attr("srcset", $(this).data('defaultimg'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<picture>

    <!-- Mobile image -->
    <source srcset="" media="(max-width:768px)">

    <!-- Virtual image with desktop image as data-defaultImage value --> 
    <img style="display: none" src="does/not/exist.jpg" alt="" class="check-img" data-defaultimg="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/420241225283674113/xoCDeFzV_400x400.jpeg">
    
    <!-- Desktop image. -->
    <img src="desktop-img-src" alt="" class="img-fluid">

</picture>
```